# Git: start over in new branch, removing commits from history

Tags: git, github, version-control

First question here!

We are using git for version control of a project. Our repo looks like this:

```
master: C0-C1-C2-C3-C4
                \            
    development: C5-C6-C7
```

When we started the project, we were advised to use gitflow workflow. Anyway, since we are a small team with no previous experience in git, working on a fairly small project, we now think that might be overkill. Instead, we'd like to start using a [feature branch model](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

Long story short, we'd like to have something like this:

```
master: C0-C1-C2-C5-C6-C7
```

So that from C7 and on, we can start over "from scratch" (but keeping what we've made until now), but now using separate branches for features.

As you can see, we'd also like to get rid of **C3** and **C4**. This is because they are completely useless (those commits add some files that were added in **C6** and **C7**), and also because we'd like to start with a single, clean master branch, without merges in our history.

I thought that would be pretty simple, but after a couple of hours googling, I'm a little bit lost. I read about creating a new orphan branch, copying the contents of C7 and then deleting my other branches, but I'm not sure that would be the right approach.

Oh, and by the way, we are not able to create a new repo. This is a private repo given to us in the context of an academic course, and it's the only one we have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
C0-C1-C2-C5-C6-C7 [master]
```

The problem becomes simpler when you look at your repository like so.

```
C0-C1-C2-C5-C6-C7 [development]
       \
        C3-C4 [master]
```

"Branches" are just labels on commits. They can be renamed and moved as you like. `development` is already where you want `master` to be.  So rename `master` and `development`.

```
git branch -m master old/master
git branch -m development master
```

Ta da!

```
C0-C1-C2-C5-C6-C7 [master]
       \
        C3-C4 [old/master]
```

Since your `master` has diverged from the remote `master` you will need to force push.

```
git push -u --force origin master
```

The `-u` will ensure your new `master` branch tracks the remote `master`.

Finally, when you're ready, delete `old/master`.

```
git branch -D old/master
```

It can still be recovered, for a while, via `git reflog`.

Comment: Um, isn't `/` reserved? I didn't know about `-m`, thanks.

Comment: @TobiaTesan `/` is not reserved. It's not even escaped. `git branch foo/bar` creates the file `.git/refs/heads/foo/bar`. I use `/` to organize my branches. `issues/123`, `feature/name`, `old/branch`, `release/1.2.3`.

Comment: The first time I tried this I got `error: src refspec master does not match any.` when pushing. Then, I tried using `old_master` instead of `old/master` and everything worked nice, **but** I had to replace `-d` for `-D` at the end, since `old_master` wasn't merged. I'd appreaciate if you edit that, please.

Comment: @SusyP What command did you use to push and what branch were you on when you did it? You shouldn't need to push old_master and the name should not have had an effect unless you're relying on push to guess based on branch name matching. Good catch on the `-D`.

Comment: I think I was at `development`, but maybe I just forgot to checkout. I think this answer would be better if you are more specific about which branch one should checkout to in which moment. Now, I remember that another minor problem when deleting `old_master` was that I was standing on that branch so I had to checkout to `master` before that.

Comment: @SusyP Unless you specify, `push` pushes the current branch. Checkout as appropriate. The rest of the commands don't care what branch you're on, or they have appropriate error messages.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer since this was the easiest method to solve **my** problem, but anyone that arrives here with a similar problem should look at @TobiaTesan 's answer, too. Thanks to both of you, guys.

Comment: @SusyP <shameless plug> while you can accept only one, you can upvote multiple answers if you feel so inclined </shameless plug>; OTH @Schwern's does the same exact thing but *better* (aka: with the shortcut `-m`, which is very handy)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
git checkout master
git branch master_backup # Save the older master repo locally just in case
git reset --hard C2 # This sets the branch to C0-C1-C2
git cherry-pick C5..C7 # This sets the branch to C0-C1-C2-C5-C6-C7
```

You may have to resolve conflicts in the last command. This won't generate any merge commits but will change some of your your SHA1's:

```
git mergetool
```

Then, replace the remote master branch:

```
git push origin :master
git push origin master:master
```

Comment: It's a valid method, but may I ask you why you'd rather `reset` and `cherry pick` things than just shuffling the pointers around?  In particular, I suppose merging *might* result in different SHA1s.

Comment: I did it this way because I didn't know about Schwern's answer. I agree his method is better.

Answer (score 0):

You may also achive this with

```
git checkout master
git rebase development
git reabse -i <SHA of initial commit> master
```

Now you can reorder, select and edit the commits you want to keep. Do not forget to push your reorginized branches and inform your coworker to pull the "new" branches so they do not push any old commits back to your repository.